# How to execute a single statement line in Node without entering in the prompt nor choosing a js script?

Tags: node.js, shell

Both in PHP and Python I have the option to execute a single command line right in the shell, without needing to enter on some REPL console and neither calling some script.[image: Sample using command line testing both in Python and PHP]
This enables me make fast checkings and testings, as using `time` from shel utility, like following:
[image: Some usefulness in doing this]
How do I do this with Node?

Comment: `echo 'console.log("like this?")' | node -`

Comment: node -e "console.log('or this?')"

Answer (score 4):

`node -e "<code>"`

Comment: Please add some explanation to help others understand  your answer

Comment: Here's the snippets from the description using this answer's pattern:

`node -e 'console.log(Math.max(2353245,356345,746574))'
2353245`

`time node -e 'console.log(Math.max(2353245,356345,746574))'
2353245
user=0.09s system=0.13s cpu=119% total=0.188`